# How to pass form data from node server to extrenal server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code. How to send my form data to external server? Can anyone solve my trouble? 
Thanks in advance.

```
var http = require('http');
var FormData = require('form-data');

var form = new FormData();

form.append('books', ['book1', 'book2']); // my form data

var options = {
  host: 'http://localhost',
  port: 8080,
  path: '/app/updateBooks',
  method: 'POST'
};

http.request(options, function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
}).on("error", function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: In order to achieve this I have been using [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Comment: Thanks @kukic I want this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Request module** can be used for sending data to external server: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

For example:

```
const request = require('request')
request({
    uri: 'https://www.example.com/',
    qs: { access_token: token },  // object containing querystring values to be appended to the uri
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData //json - sets body to JSON representation of value and adds Content-type: application/json header

  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //success condition
    } else {
      // failure condition
    }
  })
```